# Prove that for $n\ge 1$, $1^3+2^3+\dotsb+n^3> \frac{n^4}{4}$.

Tags: induction, arithmetic

> Prove that for $n\ge 1$, $1^3+2^3+\dotsb+n^3> \frac{n^4}{4}$.

I'm having a hard time to prove it. I would appreciate if you could give me some help.

Comment: Have you tried induction?  Seems like a place to start.

Comment: A good question should also include any attempt already made to answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $$\frac{n^4}4 = \int_{0}^n t^3 \; dt$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $1^3+2^3+\cdots n^3 = \dfrac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}$. Perhaps you want to show this by induction first before proceeding to show your inequality.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

If you use induction, you will have to prove that

$$\frac{n^4}{4}+(n+1)^3> \frac{(n+1)^4}{4}$$

or

$$4(n+1)^3>(n+1)^4-n^4$$